# Grails - findAll joining two tables

Tags: grails, grails-orm, findall

I'm new to Grails. I'm having problem with retrieving data from DB. I have domains with classes, something like...

```
class Lightbox {    
   String name = ''
   String link  = ''
   static hasMany = [users: LightboxUserAccount]
}

class LightboxUserAccount {
   UserAccount userAccount
   static belongsTo = [lightbox: Lightbox]  
}

class UserAccount {
   String username
   ...
}
```

I want to list all "Lightboxes" owned by user with ID=4. I was trying

```
def my_lb = Lightbox.findAll("from Lightbox as lb where lb.users=:userAccount", [userAccount: springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()])
```

or

```
def my_lb = Lightbox.findAllByUsers(4)
```

None of those work for me. What am I doing wrong? Thx

Comment: `from Lightbox as lb where lb.users.userAccount=:userAccount` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did it slightly different, using criteria instead. Take a look if interested

```
static getAllByUserAccount(UserAccount userAccount) {
    def criteria = Lightbox.createCriteria()
    def my_lb = criteria.list {
        users {
            eq('userAccount', userAccount)
        }
    }
    return my_lb
}
```

It seems to be working. Thanks for responses though

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Lightbox.findAll("from Lightbox as lb where :userAccount in (lb.users)", [userAccount: springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()])
```